# App (Android) can not connect to the server

Tags: java, android, server

I have a problem with my android application. In Android Studio, everything looks normal since no error appears. The application is supposed to connect to the web server for data recovery. But every time I test the app on my android device or on an emulator, I still have the same message: "**Appname can not connect to the server**"

So, since I do not see any error on Android studio, I do not know where to look. I tried with the coordinates of two different servers, but still the same message. I have concluded that the problem is not at the level of the connection to the server, but in my code, but where?

If anyone has any suggestion, I'm a taker. If you need to see any file, let me know.

Comment: `but in my code, but where?`. Indeed. And you do not know what to do. Interesting.

Comment: Have you tried to test the connection of your java server from another client and not from your android application?

Have you modified the permissions of your application in AndroidManifest.xml so it can use internet for connect to your server?

Comment: Hello, AndroidManifest.xml is well configured. I feel this is a bug in Android Studio 2.2.2. I also noticed that the installation of the .apk file on android is duplicated.